# How can I shrink a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql

#### I have an instance of Postgresql that is 374GB!

It's the dbase for an Event Sentry Application, but since Event Sentry is just a monitoring tool, don't see how it can require this much data.
There are hundreds of 1 Gig files in the default database folder.
Any assistance on this one is greatly appreciated! Carl
[image: Postgresql_image]

Comment: You can use the statements from the Postgres wiki to find the tables that take up the space: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this operation called 'vacuum' in PostgreSQL:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/routine-vacuuming.html

However, in some situations even vacuuming doesn't solve that much. In that case, the best to do is make a dump, recreate the database and restore it.