# How to collapse a large query on PgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin

In Visual Studio, we have the possibility to shrink a large code as in the example below:

```
#region

Code here...

#region
```

I would like to do the same in a query within my PGAdmin. It's possible?

Comment: @Emerson these posts may help you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17277/when-is-it-ok-to-shrink-a-database   or    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019147/how-can-i-shrink-a-postgresql-database

Comment: @Sergio, I think the question is not about reducing the size of database, but _collapsing_ parts of the query in the query tool.

Comment: Perfect @Sergio, collapsing parts of the query

Comment: I'm not understanding the downvotes.  The phrasing seems off, but this is a legitimate question.  OP has a clear example of what they want to accomplish.  I am not finding a solution with a quick search.  And clearly the downvoter couldn't provide a solution, link to duplicate, etc etc

Comment: Putting your query within brackets `(SELECT * FROM foobar)` will enable this feature in PgAdmin.

Comment: I removed the `sql` and `postgresql` tags since this question is very specific to usage of `pgadmin` tool. Sounds like @MichelMilezzi has the answer. :)